# Simple Custom Layer fails to build in simple model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When using a custom class to replace a lambda function, building a model fails.

I previously had this code in a lambda function and it worked fine but I was unable to save a model.  I need to save the model that I'm building which has dependencies on this code snippet.

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf 

class ShapePositionLayer(keras.layers.Layer): 

    def call(self, x):
         assert isinstance(x, list)
         a, b = x
         return keras.backend.gather(keras.backend.shape(a), b)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (1)

captions = keras.layers.Input(shape=[5,1024], name='captions')
batch_size  = ShapePositionLayer()([captions,tf.constant(0, 
dtype=tf.int32)])
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[captions], outputs=[batch_size])
```

I expected to be able to build a model.

Instead receive error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'